# How to forbid opening jQuery UI tab content in a new window?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to reject opening a new window with jQuery UI tab content by clicking using the right mouse button?

Comment: What? Are you talking about someone right clicking on a link and choosing (from the browser's context menu) "open in new window"? If so I think the only thing you could do is disable the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

This will disable the right click context menu from being activated from the tabs.

```
            $("#tabs").bind("contextmenu", function () { return false; });
```

Since the tabs use "href", the browsers will always have this option for a tab in the context menu, I d